# how to call 2 function inside 1 input type

Tags: javascript, php

```
function addRow(tableID) {
```

`var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        if (i==2) {
            newcell.innerHTML="<div id='txtHint"+xx+"'></div>";
        }
        else if(i==0){
        newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk[]'/>";
        }
        else if (i==1) {
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("onchange","showUser(this.value,"+xx+");showrole(this.value,"+xx+")");
            }
        }
        else if (i==3) {
             newcell.innerHTML="<div id='txtHintrole"+xx+"'></div>";
        }`

this is my function show select option depend on username i choose
after did some modification finally it work

and now i want to show role depend on username
so i have 2 show

1.for password
2.for username

> onchange="showpassword(this.value)

this is my onchange inside select box

and now i want to showrole too

so when i choose the select
it will showed me password and role ad diferent cell

> > newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("onchange","showUser(this.value,"+xx+");showrole(this.value,"+xx+")");

and i foudn that i have tu put semi colon to devide the function
and i still show an error that the show only show role and it happen to 2 of them

it should showpassword and showrole when i select the value

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: I think what you have to do is load the data from database into a javascript array. Then use that array of values to create the table, and add the username to the naming of the table like txhintusername1 and use that to call the function you need.

Comment: i solved it 
but now i get another problem here...
please help me again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the innerHTML property of the cell.

Do something like

```
newcell.innerHTML = '<div id="txthint' + i + '">content</div>';
```

Hope this help

Comment: could u tell me how to do it
i have tried it and it sait something like html element

what content should i put in

Comment: thanks it was worked
at the beginning i declare variabel xx=1
but with fuction like that the txthint ad first row show txthint3
not txthint1 emm

Comment: Yes xx++ is better when you are incrementing with for loops.

Comment: i want to ask another question
can i post another answer or i just need to edit the first post

Comment: I think it an be ok here